# Highlight image on tab change

Tags: javascript, html

I need your help. I need to highlight image just by dotted line on tab change means through tab when i will reach on that image it should be highlight.

I have code like:

```
<td><a href="javascript:doSubmit();"><img src="../images/sign-in-btn.jpg" alt="" width="78" height="25" /></a></td>
```

it is a image which is solving the purpose of button. When use tab it is not highlighting this image. So i need help for this.

Waiting for early response.

Thanks in Advance:
Tanu

Comment: Can you add some more details & some sample code of your attempt to do this. Thanks

Comment: change the image's border when it is on focus?

Comment: Add 4 spaces before your code block in the question, that way it will be visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with jQuery, put this line when you reach the img tab

```
jQuery("#imgId").animate( { backgroundColor: '#65A6D1' }, 500).animate( { backgroundColor: 'white' }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want your image to behave like a standard button when focused, showing the same dotted border, you just need to set the .tabIndex property on it:

```
<td>
<a href="javascript:doSubmit();">
<img src="../images/sign-in-btn.jpg" tabindex="0" alt="" width="78" height="25" />
</a></td>
```

Comment: Though, I tested that code on IE and Firefox and it worked. Maybe your image never got focused at all?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found another way. Instead of an img element, try using an input element which type is "image":

```
<td>
<a href="javascript:doSubmit();">
<input type="image" src="../images/sign-in-btn.jpg" alt="" width="78" height="25" />
</a></td>
```

These input elements normally behave like buttons when clicked or focused.